# How to display data when in grid?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to display data when toggle  list view of 8 items and grid view of 12 items in Vuejs?
My working Codepen link   https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/wvJBjKq

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  data: {
        // The layout mode, possible values are "grid" or "list".
    layout: 'grid',

        articles: [{
            "title": "What You Need To Know About CSS Variables",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2016/03/what-you-need-to-know-about-css-variables/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/css-variables.jpg",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/css-variables-150x150.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Freebie: 4 Great Looking Pricing Tables",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2016/02/freebie-4-great-looking-pricing-tables/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/great-looking-pricing-tables.jpg",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/great-looking-pricing-tables-150x150.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "20 Interesting JavaScript and CSS Libraries for February 2016",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2016/02/20-interesting-javascript-and-css-libraries-for-february-2016/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/interesting-resources-february.jpg",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/interesting-resources-february-150x150.jpg"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Quick Tip: The Easiest Way To Make Responsive Headers",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2016/02/quick-tip-easiest-way-to-make-responsive-headers/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/quick-tip-responsive-headers.png",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/quick-tip-responsive-headers-150x150.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Learn SQL In 20 Minutes",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2016/01/learn-sql-in-20-minutes/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-sql-20-minutes.png",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/learn-sql-20-minutes-150x150.png"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "Creating Your First Desktop App With HTML, JS and Electron",
            "url": "http://tutorialzine.com/2015/12/creating-your-first-desktop-app-with-html-js-and-electron/",
            "image": {
                "large": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/creating-your-first-desktop-app-with-electron.png",
                "small": "http://cdn.tutorialzine.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/creating-your-first-desktop-app-with-electron-150x150.png"
            }
        }]

  }
});
```

```html
 <div class="bar">
<a class="list-icon" v-bind:class="{ 'active': layout == 'list'}" v-on:click="layout = 'list'"></a>
<a class="grid-icon" v-bind:class="{ 'active': layout == 'grid'}" v-on:click="layout = 'grid'"></a>
 </div>
 
 <ul v-if="layout == 'grid'" class="grid">
    <li v-for="a in articles">
      <a v-bind:href="a.url" target="_blank"><img v-bind:src="a.image.large" /></a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <ul v-if="layout == 'list'" class="list">
    <li v-for="a in articles">
      <a v-bind:href="a.url" target="_blank"><img v-bind:src="a.image.small" /></a>
      <p>{{a.title}}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I am able to successfully toggle between grid and list view. But Now the issue is i need to display like
For list-view 8 items and grid-view 12 items

Answer (score 2):

I updated your codepen here : https://codepen.io/Sorakkaist/pen/yLMeggN

As mentionned by previous answer, you can use a computed reacting to the layout changes:

```
tableSize() {
    return this.layout === "grid" ?  8 : 10
 }
```

Then instead of looping on `items`, you base your v-for on another computed :

```
rows() {
    return this.items.slice(0, this.tableSize)
 },
```

in your template :

```
  <ul v-if="layout == 'grid'" class="grid">
    <!-- A view with big photos and no text -->
    <p v-for="(row, i) in rows" :index="i">{{row}}</p>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed property for that, e.g. `filteredArticles`, which will return 8 or 12 entries depending on the layout chosen using [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
computed: {
  filteredArticles () {
    return this.articles.slice(0, this.layout === 'list' ? 8 : 12);
  }
}
```

Then it is just a matter of using `filteredArticles` instead of `articles` in your `v-for` binding.

Comment: Tried above but it is not working, Can you please edit codepen if possible

https://codepen.io/santoshch/pen/wvJBjKq